# How do I add a moving average?

Tags: php

The moving averages based on 5 numbers of these win numbers is a moving part. So if the win numbers are:
3-4-5-6-7-8-4-5-6-33-23-12-5-1
Then the first moving average is based on 3-4-5-6-7 divided by 5
Then the second moving average is based on 4-5-6-7-8 divided by 5
Then the third moving average is based on 5-6-7-8-4 divided by 5

I tried creating a array but it didnt work.

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$win_numbers = [];
for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=250;$rnd++)
{
  $randoms[] = mt_rand(0,36);  // see this block for generating randoms
}

echo "Random Numbers:<br>";
echo implode('-', $randoms).PHP_EOL;

echo "<br><br>";

$i = 0;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   $i++; 
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $win_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
       $existing = [];
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd; 
}

echo "Win Numbers:<br>";
echo implode('-',$win_numbers);

echo "<br><br>";

echo "Moving Averages:<br>";



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way, Also it can be optimize with couple of methods like `array_sum()` and `array_slice()`

```
<?php
// Function to print moving average
function movingAverage($win_numbers, $average_for)  
{ 
    foreach($win_numbers as $key=>$value){
      $win_number_consecutive_5 = array_slice($win_numbers, $key, $average_for);
      if(count($win_number_consecutive_5) == $average_for) {
      $win_averages[] = array_sum($win_number_consecutive_5) / $average_for;
  }
    }
    return $win_averages;
} 

echo "Moving Averages:<br>";
$win_numbers = explode('-','3-4-5-6-7-8-4-5-6-33-23-12-5-1');
$average_for = 5;
echo implode('-',movingAverage($win_numbers, $average_for));
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GO0Ai

Comment: It doesn't update yet based on the win numbers. If I refresh it doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop the array with a for loop and use array_slice then you can get a rolling average.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($randoms)-4;$i++){
    $avg[] = array_sum(array_slice($randoms, $i, 5))/5;
}
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/XUdlP